# Растянуть div по оставшийся высоте родительского div a

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Добрый день как растянуть `div.cooking` по оставшийся высоте родительского `div.recipe_slider_item_decr`?

```css
.recipe_slider_item_wrap{
  height: 915px
}
.recipe_slider_item_decr{
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="recipe_slider_item_wrap">

          <div class="recipe_slider_item_decr">
            <div class="recipe_slider_item_header">
              <h2>Рецепт котлет для годовалого малыша</h2>
              <p>В правилах здорового питания рекомендуется отказаться от жарки.</p>
              <div class="underline"></div>
              <p>Приготовление куриных котлет для детей от года по этому рецепту сделает прием пищи здоровым.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="recipe_slider_item_ingredients">
              <p>Для его приготовления возьмите:</p>
              <ul>
                <li>800 г куриное мясо (грудка);</li>
                <li>150 г овсяные хлопья;</li>
                <li>2 крупные луковицы;</li>
                <li>2 зубка чеснок;</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="cooking" id="scroll">
              <p>Все компоненты нужно перекрутить с помощью мясорубки. Из подсоленного фарша формируются котлетки. К фаршу добавляют измельченную зелень (петрушку, укроп). Яйцо можно не добавлять, так как овсяные хлопья служат хорошим связующим. Без него котлеты получаются более воздушными, мягкими.
              Можно приступать к запеканию. Керамические формы нужно заполнить водой на полсантиметра и выложить сформированные котлеты. Закрытые сверху фольгой формы помещают в нагретую до 180–200 градусов духовку и запекают.</p>
              <p></p>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: А разве запечёное мясо можно называть котлетами? Лучше уж на пару! И у вас в ингридиентах про зелень ничего не сказано, недоработка.

Comment: @Klimenkomud будто это конечный результат это я просто продублировал слайды и не до конца отредактировал, мне не нужно чтоб мне тут подсказали правильный ли написано содержимое текста, тут как бы другой вопрос

Comment: Да вы уже собственно нашли ответ, это просто шутка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать flex

```css
.recipe_slider_item_decr{
  height: 915px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
.recipe_slider_item_header,recipe_slider_item_ingredients{
   flex-shrink:0
 }
.cooking{
   flex:1 0 auto;
   background-color:#cda;
   /*для наглядности*/
}
```

```html
<div class="recipe_slider_item_wrap">

          <div class="recipe_slider_item_decr">
            <div class="recipe_slider_item_header">
              <h2>Рецепт котлет для годовалого малыша</h2>
              <p>В правилах здорового питания рекомендуется отказаться от жарки.</p>
              <div class="underline"></div>
              <p>Приготовление куриных котлет для детей от года по этому рецепту сделает прием пищи здоровым.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="recipe_slider_item_ingredients">
              <p>Для его приготовления возьмите:</p>
              <ul>
                <li>800 г куриное мясо (грудка);</li>
                <li>150 г овсяные хлопья;</li>
                <li>2 крупные луковицы;</li>
                <li>2 зубка чеснок;</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="cooking" id="scroll">
              <p>Все компоненты нужно перекрутить с помощью мясорубки. Из подсоленного фарша формируются котлетки. К фаршу добавляют измельченную зелень (петрушку, укроп). Яйцо можно не добавлять, так как овсяные хлопья служат хорошим связующим. Без него котлеты получаются более воздушными, мягкими.
              Можно приступать к запеканию. Керамические формы нужно заполнить водой на полсантиметра и выложить сформированные котлеты. Закрытые сверху фольгой формы помещают в нагретую до 180–200 градусов духовку и запекают.</p>
              <p></p>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Все работает, появился тогда вопрос как добавить ему скролл div.cooking если его содержимое будет превышать размер по высоте?

Comment: overflow-y: scroll; не работает в таком случае и границы этого дива начинают растягивается по контенту

Comment: Задать max-height для div.cooking и overflow-y:auto.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы растянуть div.cooking по оставшейся высоте - просто задайте ему высоту выше 70%. У родительского div можно добавить overflow:hidden на тот случай если что-то попробует вылезти.

Comment: Если же вы хотите расстянуть содержимое, то тут нужно поступить немного иначе.

Comment: div.cooking будет добавлен скролл в случае если его содержимое будет превышать высоту, а выше 70% не подходит потому что границы дива выходить за нижней границы div.recipe_slider_item_decr, а должно быть ровно по его нижней границе

Comment: Ну свойствой overflow:hidden обрезает все что вылезает за пределы div. Если задать 67% то должно быть ровно по размеру родительского div

Comment: ну хорошо, а если содержимое выше .cooking будет меньше или больше то опять все полезет, дело в том что это слайдер и на одном слайде одно расстояние до нижней границы родительского div в другом слайде другое расстояние, вот в чем проблема

Comment: Тогда рекомендую использовать процентное соотношение при указании размеров. В том числе высота родительского div